# how can i know what data is being sent or received from all the apps installed on my android device?

Tags: android, security, mobile

i am trying to build an android application which will display the user what data was sent from all apps and what data was received on all apps installed on the device.

I have searched but nothing came which could give me a start. Is there any encryption/decryption techniques used(Since i have no idea about the same).

It would be a privilege if i get to know where to start with this project.

Comment: You app would need root to do this

Comment: Thanks. Where can i get the code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking more about a `background service` running all the time, but that's really complicated if you don't have clear idea on how they works.

Start with this: `http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html`

I don't really know if `Android` let you spoof this kind of information about other apps, but if yes, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but i know about the background service. What i am  trying to create is an app which will let you know what kind of data is sent from other apps installed on your device and what kind of data is received by all other apps on your device.